# Creating groupings in JQ from a raw file

Tags: jq

So, I have a .netrc file that looks like this:

```
machine foo
login usera
password somepass
machine somehost
login userb
password otherpass
```

And I am trying to get it into an array of object, grouped in sets of 3, which I can then sort and select out uniq ones (yes, there are probably other, non jq ways...)

And I keep getting lost. Here's what I have:

```bash
jq -Rs '
split("\n") |
map(select(length > 0)) |
    map(split(" ") |
            to_entries | group_by(.key % 2 == 0)
    ) |
    map(
        map(.[0].value )
    ) |
    map({
        (.[1]) : .[0]
    }) | add'
' ~/.netrc
```

expected

```json
[
  {
    "machine": "foo",
    "login": "usera",
    "password": "somepass"
  },
  {
    "machine": "somehost",
    "login": "userb",
    "password": "otherpass"
  }
]
```

I'd love to see something slick to solve this

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach simply splitting at whitespaces, then interpreting the first two words from each line as key and value, respectively.

```bash
jq -Rn '[[inputs | [splits("\\s+")] | {(.[0]):.[1]}] | _nwise(3) | add]'
```

```json
[
  {
    "machine": "foo",
    "login": "usera",
    "password": "somepass"
  },
  {
    "machine": "somehost",
    "login": "userb",
    "password": "otherpass"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vb8WRt9auUO)

Notes:

- If you want to disregard empty lines, replace `inputs` with `inputs | select(length > 0)`. If you want to also disregard any whitespace-only lines, replace with `inputs | select(test("\\S"))` instead.
- If you want to allow for key-only lines, provide a default which is then used as value instead (e.g. the empty string `""`) by changing `.[1]` to `(.[1] // "")`.
- If you want the entire rest of the line be the value, not just the second word (i.e. including all subsequent whitespaces as is), replace `[splits("\\s+")]` with `scan("(\\S+)(?:\\s+(.*))?")`.
- If you're uncomfortable using undocumented `_nwise` for the grouping, replace it with `while(has(0);.[3:])[:3]`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'd call this *"slick"*, but here's one `jq` filter that can do it (using `--null-input` and `--raw-input` options).

N.B.:  If you have any non-word characters (like `-`), you may want to use something like `scan("[^\\s]+")`, or equivalently `scan("\\S+")` instead.  I.e., anything that is not in the space character class.

```
[inputs| [scan("\\w+"), (input_line_number/3|ceil)]]
| group_by(.[2])
| map(map({(.[0]): .[1]})|add)
```

or as a one-liner for your `~/.netrc` file:

```
jq --null-input --raw-input '[inputs| [scan("\\w+"), (input_line_number/3|ceil)]] | group_by(.[2]) | map(map({(.[0]): .[1]})|add)' ~/.netrc
```

Output, given the example input:

```json
[
  {
    "machine": "foo",
    "login": "usera",
    "password": "somepass"
  },
  {
    "machine": "somehost",
    "login": "userb",
    "password": "otherpass"
  }
]
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/l-4KTfQH2SF).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
jq --null-input --raw-input\
  'reduce (inputs | scan("(\\w+) (.*)")) as [$k,$v] (
   [] ; .[(input_line_number / 3 | ceil - 1)][$k] = $v
   )' ~/.netrc
```